# display events in a php calendar

Tags: php, sql, calendar

I am building a PHP calendar, which is connected to a database containing a list of dates.  I have managed to build the calendar, connect  to the database, and display the dates.  However instead of simply changing the class of the  if the date is found in the database, I am getting duplicate dates.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
/* program name: Build Calender */
/* description: build calender */
/* 1 -> build table */
/* 2 -> add headings */
/* 3 -> add blanks */
/* 4 -> connect to db */
/* 5 -> check if dates in db = dates in calendar */
/* 6 ->  td with diff id */
/* 7 -> add remaining blanks */

$month = (int) (isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year =  (int) (isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

echo "<h1 style='float:left; padding-right:30px;'>".date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year))." ".$year."</h1>";

$next = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Next</a>';

/* "previous month" control */
$previous = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control">Previous </a>';

$controls = $previous."|".$next;
echo $controls;

$headings = array(0 =>'mon','tue','wed','thurs','fri','sat','sun');
$running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,0,$year));
$days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
$days_in_this_week = 1;
$day_counter = 1;
$dates_array = array();
$gourmet_type = "";

echo"<table border='1px'>\n";
for ($weeks = 0; $weeks<= 5 ; $weeks++)
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
    for ($days = 0; $days <= 6 ; $days++)
    {
        if($weeks == 0)
        {
            echo"<td>".$headings[$days]."</td>\n";  
        }
        else if ($weeks == 1 && $days < $running_day)  //Generates first row
        {
            echo "<td class='day-cell'>"."yy"."</td>\n";
        }
        else if ($day_counter <= $days_in_month)  //Adds the rest of the days
        {
        // varialbes for day-cell //
            $available  = "<td class='day-cell available' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
            $lunch = "<td class='day-cell lunch' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
            $dinner = "<td class='day-cell dinner' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
            $fullday = "<td class='day-cell fullday' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
            echo $available;
            $datestring = $day_counter.".".$month.".".$year;
            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
            $db_link = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$password") or die('Cannot connect');
            mysql_select_db("$database",$db_link) or die('Cannot select the DB');
            $query = "SELECT * FROM reservations";
            $result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            if  ($row['date_of_reservation'] == $datestring && $row['reservationType'] == "LUNCH")
                { 
                    echo $lunch;                     
                }
                else if ($row['date_of_reservation'] ==  $datestring &&  $row['reservationType'] == "DINNER")
                {
                    echo $dinner;
                }
                else if ($row['date_of_reservation'] == $datestring && $row['reservationType'] == "FULLDAY")
                {
                    echo $fullday;
                }
            }
            $day_counter++;
            }
        else  //Adds the blanks at the end
        {
            echo "<td class='day-cell'>"."yy"."</td>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
}
echo "</table>";
```

?>

This is the result I'm getting in my browser:

```
<h1 style='float:left; padding-right:30px;'>April 2015</h1><a href="?month=3&year=2015" class="control">Previous </a>|<a href="?month=5&year=2015" class="control">Next</a>
<table border='1px'>
<tr>
   <td>mon</td>
   <td>tue</td>
   <td>wed</td>
   <td>thurs</td>
   <td>fri</td>
   <td>sat</td>
   <td>sun</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class='day-cell'>yy</td>
   <td class='day-cell'>yy</td>
   <td class='day-cell available' id='1'>1</td> <!--should hide -->
   <td class='day-cell dinner' id='1'>1</td>
   <td class='day-cell available' id='2'>2</td>
   <td class='day-cell available' id='3'>3</td>
   <td class='day-cell available' id='4'>4</td>
   <td class='day-cell available' id='5'>5</td> <!--should hide -->
   <td class='day-cell lunch' id='5'>5</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='day-cell available' id='6'>6</td>
    <td class='day-cell available' id='7'>7</td>
    <td class='day-cell available' id='8'>8</td>
    <td class='day-cell available' id='9'>9</td>
    <td class='day-cell fullday' id='9'>9</td>
    <td class='day-cell available' id='10'>10</td>
    <td class='day-cell available' id='11'>11</td>
    <td class='day-cell available' id='12'>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td class='day-cell available' id='13'>13</td>
     <td class='day-cell available' id='14'>14</td>
     <td class='day-cell available' id='15'>15</td>
     <td class='day-cell available' id='16'>16</td>
     <td class='day-cell available' id='17'>17</td> <!--should hide -->
     <td class='day-cell lunch' id='17'>17</td>
     <td class='day-cell available' id='18'>18</td> <!--should hide -->
     <td class='day-cell dinner' id='18'>18</td>
     <td class='day-cell available' id='19'>19</td> <!--should hide -->
     <td class='day-cell lunch' id='19'>19</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='20'>20</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='21'>21</td> <!--should hide -->
      <td class='day-cell lunch' id='21'>21</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='22'>22</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='23'>23</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='24'>24</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='25'>25</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='26'>26</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='27'>27</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='28'>28</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='29'>29</td>
      <td class='day-cell available' id='30'>30</td> <!--should hide -->
      <td class='day-cell lunch' id='30'>30</td>
      <td class='day-cell'>yy</td>
      <td class='day-cell'>yy</td>
      <td class='day-cell'>yy</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your need to handle $available and $lunch,$dinner,$fullday properly.I have tried to change.Please check

```
<?php
    /* program name: Build Calender */
    /* description: build calender */
    /* 1 -> build table */
    /* 2 -> add headings */
    /* 3 -> add blanks */
    /* 4 -> connect to db */
    /* 5 -> check if dates in db = dates in calendar */
    /* 6 ->  td with diff id */
    /* 7 -> add remaining blanks */

    $month = (int) (isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
    $year =  (int) (isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

    echo "<h1 style='float:left; padding-right:30px;'>".date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year))." ".$year."</h1>";

    $next = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Next</a>';

    /* "previous month" control */
    $previous = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control">Previous </a>';

    $controls = $previous."|".$next;
    echo $controls;

    $headings = array(0 =>'mon','tue','wed','thurs','fri','sat','sun');
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,0,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 1;
    $dates_array = array();
    $gourmet_type = "";

    echo"<table border='1px'>\n";
    for ($weeks = 0; $weeks<= 5 ; $weeks++)
    {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        for ($days = 0; $days <= 6 ; $days++)
        {
            if($weeks == 0)
            {
                echo"<td>".$headings[$days]."</td>\n";  
            }
            else if ($weeks == 1 && $days < $running_day)  //Generates first row
            {
                echo "<td class='day-cell'>"."yy"."</td>\n";
            }
            else if ($day_counter <= $days_in_month)  //Adds the rest of the days
            {
            // varialbes for day-cell //
                $available  = "<td class='day-cell available' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
                $lunch = "<td class='day-cell lunch' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
                $dinner = "<td class='day-cell dinner' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
                $fullday = "<td class='day-cell fullday' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
                //echo $available;
                $toshow="";
                $datestring = $day_counter.".".$month.".".$year;
                /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
                $db_link = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$password") or die('Cannot connect');
                mysql_select_db("$database",$db_link) or die('Cannot select the DB');
                $query = "SELECT * FROM reservations";
                $result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                if  ($row['date_of_reservation'] == $datestring && $row['reservationType'] == "LUNCH")
                    { 
                       $toshow=$lunch;                     
                    }
                    else if ($row['date_of_reservation'] ==  $datestring &&  $row['reservationType'] == "DINNER")
                    {
                        $toshow=$dinner;
                    }
                    else if ($row['date_of_reservation'] == $datestring && $row['reservationType'] == "FULLDAY")
                    {
                       $toshow=$fullday;
                    }

                }

                if($toshow==""){
                echo $available;
                }
                else{
                echo $toshow;
                }

                $day_counter++;
                }
            else  //Adds the blanks at the end
            {
                echo "<td class='day-cell'>"."yy"."</td>\n";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>\n"; 
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not very good at php.But I think your code at

```
$fullday = "<td class='day-cell fullday' id='$day_counter'>".$day_counter."</td>\n";
echo $available;
```

this echo will output all of your `class='day-cell available'` dt.

So i think this echo should be moved to the last else in your `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` loop.

Looks like

```
else if ($row['date_of_reservation'] == $datestring && $row['reservationType'] == "FULLDAY")
            {
                echo $fullday;
            }
else 
     {
                echo $available;
     }
```